# Travis CI not connecting to PostgreSQL 11.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci, postgresql-11

I'm having trouble with a build of a Rails application for a PostgreSQL 11.2 database.

Here's the `.travis.yml` file:

```
rvm:
  - 2.6.1
dist: xenial
services:
  - postgresql
addons:
  postgresql: "11.2"
  apt:
    packages:
      - postgresql-11
before_script:
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'create database kpdotcom_test;' -U postgres
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - bundle exec rake db:schema:load
```

However, the build fails:

[image]

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem too. Here's the config file that fixed it for me:

This script:

1. Shuts down all 9.* postgreSQL databases
2. installs 11.2 (at the time of this writing)
3. copies the authentication information from the old 9.6 configuration
4. creates a role called "travis"

```
language: ruby
rvm: 2.6.2
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get --yes remove postgresql\*
  - sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-11 postgresql-client-11
  - sudo cp /etc/postgresql/{9.6,11}/main/pg_hba.conf
  - sudo service postgresql restart 11  
before_script:
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE {{your database name here}};' -U postgres
  - psql -c 'CREATE ROLE travis SUPERUSER LOGIN CREATEDB;' -U postgres
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
script: bundle exec rake spec
services:
  - postgresql
addons:
  postgresql: "11.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Wheeler's answer helped me a lot. However I needed to install postgres 11 on `focal` distro whereas the initial post uses `xenial`.

Turned out I had to tweak a little bit travis' config file. I thought that might help anyone trying to install postgres 11 on `focal`. Basically you need to:

- import the repository signing key (`wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`)
- add repository contents to Ubuntu 20.04 system (`echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql-pgdg.list`)
- install PostgreSQL 11 (`sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y install postgresql-11 postgresql-client-11`)
- change pg config files:

  - change port (`port = 5433/port = 5432`)
  - ease postgres user access (`peer/trust`)
- change access rights `sudo chmod 750 /var/lib/postgresql/11/main`

Here is the script:

```yaml
before_install:
  - sudo apt -y remove postgresql\*
  - wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  - echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql-pgdg.list
  - sudo apt -y update
  - sudo apt -y install postgresql-11 postgresql-client-11
  - sudo sed -i 's/port = 5433/port = 5432/' /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf
  - sudo sed -i 's/local   all             postgres                                peer/local   all             postgres                                trust/' /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf
  - sudo chmod 750 /var/lib/postgresql/11/main
  - sudo service postgresql restart 11
```

I could keep `before_script` as it was given by Jonathan Wheeler.

If unsure, you can check the postgres port adding a temp line in the script: `echo $(sudo cat /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf)` and search for `port = 543` in the logs.

Same for postgres auth method:
`echo $(sudo cat /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf)`